# Load events into linear calendar

Tags: php, css

I am trying to create a leave planner and I would like to share my goals and ask for your opinions!

On the web page I have:

- A linear calendar that shows all months built with PHP
- A list box for the  years
- A list box with some names
- The calendar was built using PHP.
- It’s possible to add, delete an update events.
- The events are kept in a database.
- Each event as its own ‘class’ that will be used by CSS to color the
  ‘td’ elements in the calendar
- An Event as some fields: StartDate, EndDate, Type, AllDayEvent, Notes

Questions:

- The events should be loaded at the same time the calendar is created?
- It’s possible to load the events after the calendar is created avoiding
  to reload the entire page?

**Which of these approaches is the best?**

**What is the best method to load the events into the calendar? What should I use?**

Regards,
Elio Fernandes

Comment: 1. yes for the initial days that are shown, 2. ajax + json data source

Comment: Initial days?! The linear calendar as all month in it. How can I get the events from SQL Server 2012 in JSON format?

Comment: Sorry I meant initial year. Showing an empty table/list on page load might not be a good idea if the year already contains events. You might need a bridge between MSSQL and the interface. Define your queries, for example select by date or select by person and then write your endpoints in PHP. Then call those endpoints via AJAX from the interface.